# Sharepoint 2013 Wiki's - Home page

Tags: 2013, wiki

I'm looking to find something with the WIKI's that will help me find blank pages, top pages, highest rated, top contributor etc and display them on the "home" page like mediawiki. Anyone know if this is possible or if I need web parts to do this?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0):

1. Blank pages -A management issue.  Hunt them down according to a management schedule and get rid of them.  Could be done with a stored SQL procedure.
2. Top pages - First you will need to define 'Top'
3. Highest Rated - Would require either code or a field added to the wiki metadata allowing the reader to rate the article either numerically, or qualitatively transformed to a numeric. A workflow could  pop to request the rating and put the results in a metrics site list for a pivot table view on a dashboard page.  BUT Who could rate and how do you know they read the article?
4. Top Contributor - Workflow or code - On save, if 'changes' is true and, if change is significant enough, store user ident, article ident or title, and byte-count of change to a list in a metrics site and use a pivot to determine the top     contributor for the Most Prolific Prose Prize. BUT  How many bytes of change is significant?